# MVP, should the Presenter or the View be created in the Main()

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, mef, mvp

Ive been battling with MVP, specifically how to get the program to start for longer than i will admit. Currently i create an instance of all classes in program.cs. I then just call application.Run(userInterface); Below is a section from my existing setup.

```
static void Main()
{
    //...

    Status _status = new Status();
    Logger _logger = new Logger(entity, readerWriter, true);
    VerifyRow _verifyRow = new VerifyRow(entity, _logger);
    VerificationOfDataTypes _verification = new VerificationOfDataTypes(entity, _logger, _verifyRow, _status, readerWriter);

    var verify = new CsvFileVerification(entityVerification, _verification, _logger);

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var source = new CancellationTokenSourceWrapper();

    var presenter = new MainPresenter(userInterface, browser, helper, entity, verify, source);
    Application.Run(userInterface);
}
```

The way i have MVP setup atm, the MainView implements IMainView. The presenter then has IMainView injected into its constructor, along with a load of other classes.

```
    public MainPresenter(IMainForm view, IFileDialog dialog, IMainPresenterHelper helper, IUserInputEntity entity, ICsvFileVerification verify, ICancellationTokenSource source)
    {
        _view = view;
        _dialog = dialog;
        _helper = helper;
        _entity = entity;
        _verify = verify;
        _source = source;

        view.ComposeCollectionOfControls += ComposeCollectionOfControls;
        view.SelectCsvFilePath += SelectCsvFilePath;
        view.SelectErrorLogFilePath += SelectErrorLogFilePath;
        view.DataVerification += DataVerification;
    }
```

Ive been told MEF or an IOC container would help tidy this up but Im still unsure as to how i should be structuring this. I have a gut feeling that the presenter should be created first, but then i would have a random variable declared in my Main() method which would then not be used. Also how then would the View be created?

I got a console application working with MEF earlier but i couldnt figure out how to make the jump to winforms/winforms with mvp.

Any pointers on this would really be appreciated.

**Edit**, ive tried the following but cant get the following to work. Its actually trying to create 2 views. How can i reference the original View which was created by

```
"Application.Run(new Form1());"
```

in the Program.cs

The below is what i had changed the Form1 class to.

```
namespace Mini_MVP_MEF
{
    [Export(typeof(IView))]
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IView
    {
        private IPresenter _presenter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _presenter = Program._myContainer.GetExport<IPresenter>().Value;
        }

        //....

    }
}
```

Also just tried to call the following method just after the InitializeComponents(); in Form1

```
    private static void PopulateContainer()
    {
        var presenter = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Presenter.MVPPresenter).Assembly);
        var model = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Model.MVPModel).Assembly);
        var view = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(model, presenter, view);
        _myContainer = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
    }
```

but its not working either.

Answer (score 2):

A presenter without a view does not make sense. It should be created inside the view where the view will pass itself to the presenter.

eg:

```
public class MainView : IMainView
{
    IMainPresenter _presenter;
    public MainView()
    {
       _presenter = new MainPresenter(this);
    }
}
```

BTW, also make sure your view has injectable presenter, eg. another constructor where you can inject the presenter for unit tests

Comment: +1. Im still not sure how MEF would be applied though. I had found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258681/Windows-Forms-Modular-App-using-MEF but i havent had a chance to have a proper look through it.

Comment: This doesn't take MEF into account, you need the [ImportingConstructor] attribute and to let MEF instantiate the Presenter.

Comment: This is not correct, at least for Passive View implementation of MVP.  The Presenter should have a View, not the other way around.  The Presenter would expose a reference to the view, however, which would be used with Application.Run(presenter.View);

Comment: Why is an interface used for the presenter? Is it just empty, preventing any 'illegal' coupling?